# How to correctly set text of input field from script in Unity Engine?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have developer console in my game and when you press up arrow it'll load previous command that you used, to input filed. But when I try to change text from script I'll write the previous command to the input filed but the input filed is not editable anymore until you press esc key.

I am using the new TMPro.TMP_InputField.

```cs
inputField.text = typedCommands[(typedCommands.Count) - backCount];
inputField.caretPosition = inputField.text.Length;
```

On the first line I am setting text variable of the input field and on the second one I am setting cursor behind tha last character in the input field.

When I try to delete all text from the input filed from editor when the game is running I get this error:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
TMPro.TMP_InputField.GenerateCaret (UnityEngine.UI.VertexHelper vbo, UnityEngine.Vector2 roundingOffset) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.0/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_InputField.cs:3304)
TMPro.TMP_InputField.OnFillVBO (UnityEngine.Mesh vbo) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.0/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_InputField.cs:3271)
TMPro.TMP_InputField.UpdateGeometry () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.0/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_InputField.cs:3209)
TMPro.TMP_InputField.Rebuild (UnityEngine.UI.CanvasUpdate update) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.0/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_InputField.cs:3184)
UnityEngine.UI.CanvasUpdateRegistry.PerformUpdate () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/CanvasUpdateRegistry.cs:198)
UnityEngine.Canvas:SendWillRenderCanvases()
```

It seems that the input field change its value but it doesn't see that there is some text in itself that you did not type directly in it.

EDIT:

Here is more code for better understanding. I call this piece of code from the update loop.

```cs
    private void typedCommandFunc()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && backCount != (typedCommands.Count))
            backCount++;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && backCount > 0)
            backCount--;

        if(backCount != 0)
        {
            inputField.text = typedCommands[(typedCommands.Count) - backCount];
            inputField.caretPosition = inputField.text.Length;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: `When I try to delete all text from the input filed from editor...` is the variable `typedCommands` linked to that `input field` you are mentioning?

Comment: Sorry @Kaynn I didn't post enough code. You can check the first edit for my question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error log, it seems like the problem is with generating the caret:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   TMPro.TMP_InputField.**GenerateCaret**(UnityEng...

It might not be possible to make a caret right after where the string ends, try:

```
inputField.caretPosition = inputField.text.Length -1;
```

instead.

If you really wanted to make a caret right after the string ends, use the same code, but have a blank white-space at the end of the input-field.
It gives an illusion to the player where the caret is at the end of the string (Though, it is just at an empty white-space).

Also, it is possible for your `typedCommands` to have nothing and you might be still accessing it, so hence you might want to do:

```
if(backCount != 0 && typedCommands.Count != 0)
```

Comment: Behaviour is same as the previos one. But if you have at least two previos commands and you hit up arrow twice then three times down arrow you will get the same command that you would get if you would hit down arrow twice but this time you can normaly edit the command that you got.

Answer (score 0):

typedCommands.Count returns the length of typedCommands. Whenever backCount is equal to 0 the code actually reads typedCommands[typedCommands.Count]. This won't work since an array starts at 0 and typedCommands.Count will start counting at one and will return a value that is one outside of the bounds of the array.

You should always subtract 1 from the count to stay inside the bounds of the array like so:

```
inputField.text = typedCommands[typedCommands.Count - 1 - backCount];
```

Comment: Thanks for replay @ThowV I know that I am doing it wrong but I removed minus one because when you have one item in the list (count is one) and backCount is one (you want to type previous command) it's 1-1-1 which is -1. I need to rethink this part.